# Check if URL contains href of link I already clicked

Tags: jquery, duplicates

In a list I have a few links:

```
 <ul class="dropdowner" id="coll-filter">
    <li><a href="#black">Black</a></li>
    <li><a href="#white">White</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

Another output I have uses + instead of # in the url Ie:

```
  <ul class="dropdowner" id="coll-filter">
    <li><a href="+black">Black</a></li>
    <li><a href="+white">White</a></li>
    <li><a href="+blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I click the link White then "#white" is inserted into my URL. (mydomain.com/#white) 
I want to avoid duplicates so is there a way to check if "#white" already exist in URL and if so don't allow the link to be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Javascript `window.location.hash` call to determine what the current URL anchor is and base your logic on that:

```
$('.dropdowner a').click(function (event) {
   if ($(this).attr('href')==window.location.hash){
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: is there anyway to match a keyword? I am using the hash tag but in some situations my output is us using "+" as well ie: "+white"

Answer (score 1):

The following will both disable a link which matches the component of the URL after the # or + as well an enable any previously disabled links:

```
$('.dropdowner a').on('click', function() {
    var url = window.location,
        tag = url.split('+'),
        hash = window.location.hash,
        supress = function(term) {
            $('.dropdowner a[href=' + term + ']').bind('click', false);
        };      
    $('.dropdowner a').unbind('click', false);
    if (hash) {            
        supress(hash);
    } else if (typeof tag !== 'undefined') {            
        supress('+' + tag);
    }        
});
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/bind/
- http://api.jquery.com/unbind/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for - location.hash gives you the current anchor hash from the URL

```
$(function(){

    $('ul.dropdowner').find('a').click(function() {

        if ($(this).attr('href') == location.hash) {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This act like you said by default.
if the url contain #value1 of any kind
it will *not* duplicate  and the url can never looks like : #value1#value1