# Check for duplicates in URL

Tags: jquery, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if URL contains href of link I already clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903961/check-if-url-contains-href-of-link-i-already-clicked)

Some of my URLS are resulting in this:

```
mydomain.com/t-shirts+white+white
```

Is there a way to filter that out???

Jquery:

```
$('#coll-filter li a').one('click', function () {
  jQuery(this).attr("href", window.location.href  + '+' +$(this).attr('href'));
    jQuery('#coll-filter li a').each(function() { 
       if (window.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) != -1) {
             alert("no")
         }

    });

 });
```

Comment: Sure, just cut out the last "+white". (I think you need to be a bit more specific about problem and situation)

Comment: I am using tag filters and don't wan the user to be able to click the same tag twice

Comment: huh? Is your question why? if so send some code.

Comment: The problem is not your URL handling, it is that your page allows your user to double click things to produce an incorrect URL

Comment: You question was answered when you asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903961/check-if-url-contains-href-of-link-i-already-clicked/12904021#12904021  (take a look at the edited answer which accounts for the new condition you edited into the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would remove the duplicate filters:

```
function removeDupFilters(str) {
    var pos = str.search(/\/.*?$/), path, items, map = {}, i;
    if (pos !== -1) {
        path = str.substr(pos + 1);
        items = path.split("+");
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            map[items[i]] = true;
        }
        items = [];
        for (i in map) {
            items.push(i);
        }
        return str.substr(0, pos + 1) + items.join("+");
    }
    return str;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ntb8f/

Using it in your code, it would be:

```
$('#coll-filter li a').one('click', function (e) {
    var url = removeDupFilters(window.location.href + '+' + $(this).attr('href'));
    if (url !== window.location.href) {
        // go to the new URL
        window.location.href = url;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or, you could just check the current URL directly without using that function like this:

```
$('#coll-filter li a').one('click', function (e) {
    var filter = $(this).attr('href');
    var re = new RegExp("/|\\+" + filter + "$|\\+", "i");
    if (!re.test(window.location.href)) {
        // go to the new URL
        window.location.href = window.location.href + "+" + filter;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Nice! However, I have alot of tags and will have different variations so this ""mydomain.com/t-shirts+white+white" is not going to be the same out put ever time...

Comment: @user992731 - This function works independent of the domain.  It takes the part after the last `/` and assumes that is where the filters are and it just operates on that part.  It should work with any domain, any path before the last `/`.  If you want to make a function that just operates on the filters part, that is even easier (remove parts of this function).

Comment: So am I able to say something like this? window.location.href = removeDupFilters(window.location.href);

Comment: @user992731 - That would be a very inefficient way to do it because it loads the page twice and you'd have to make sure you would never get stuck in an infinite loop loading the page over and over again.  You should intercept the place where the filters are being built and remove the dups BEFORE the browser is sent to the new page so the browser only loads the page once with no dups.

Comment: "$(this).attr('href')= removeDupFilters($(this).attr('href'))"

Comment: any ideas on how to go about so make this call and your call your function. $(this).attr("href", window.location.href  + '+' +$(this).attr('href'));

Comment: @user992731 - I don't know what you're trying to do in your jsFiddle, but look at the code options I've added to my answer.  If you use `removeDupFilters()`, you call it on the fully constructed URL, not on a single filter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18077/discussion-between-user992731-and-jfriend00)

Comment: Doh! The function breaks if I the the tags are not next to each other: t-shirts+white+t-shirts

Comment: @user992731 - the `removeDupFilters()` function doesn't care what the order of the tags is.  It is not order sensitive.

Comment: It breaks. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/ntb8f/4/

Comment: @user992731 - For reasons I'm not sure, you weren't using the latest/correct version of the code in the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ntb8f/.  The correct version doesn't show that problem.

Comment: @user992731 - so what's wrong with your jsFiddle?  It doesn't run because there's no HTML and thus no way to trigger your code.  The dup function looks like it's in the right place.